# Deleting an element from redis list having stringified JSON as element of list in Node.js

Tags: json, node.js, redis

I want to delete comment belonging to a post from redis. I am using list as my data structure. I tried using the LREM command(**Syntax**: LREM Key count **value**), but the value in my case is a stringified JSON object. So to  delete any comment for given post, everytime I have to put that whole JSON as the value in LREM. The JSON looks as:

"{\"_id\":\"5935374b535\",\"author\":{\"_id\":\"58382eae771\",\"user_id\":\"58382eae77149\",\"username\":\"hello_37\",,\"post_id\":{\"_id\":\"5919abd3b6a\",\"images\":[],\"description\":\"\",\"title\":\"Testing post\"},\"user_id\":\"58382eae77149d3d02204369\",\"mentions\":[\" cool comment5\"]\"is_approved\":true,\"text\":\" cool comment5\",\"__v\":0}"

This works, but is not a good approach. Can I delete the comment just using id for that comment(_id)? I am not able to find any command for deletion in list other LREM which uses the complete value of element in list.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using storing each comment as a single entity, i.e create keys like so: `POST:{userId}:{postId}:{commentId}` and the corresponding value as a string. So if you want to delete a key you can simply say `del POST:{userId}:{postId}:{commentId}`. This is `O(1)` compared to `O(N)` for `LREM`. If you want to retrieve all the posts of a user then `keys POST:{userId}:*` will list all the posts' comments keys in redis and likewise for a post you can say `keys POST:{userId}:{postId}:*`

Comment: My final aim is to fetch all the comments for a given post. So, user_id doesn't seem to play any role as such. I was storing post_id as the key and the complete comment object in stringified form as value. Can you please clarify how are you deleting the comment which is a string from the redis using list?

Comment: I am not using a list at all.